# On the Possibility of Godel Numbering

Tags: number-theory, logic, incompleteness

I've gotten to the point of the book `Godel, Escher, Bach` which really gets into demonstrating the mechanisms of Godel's incompleteness proof. I've had to go back and forth through it a few times, and have been bouncing it off of Cantor's diagonal proof, as the author intends. But I think I've reached a point that is unintended and not sure how to resolve it.

If any natural number is itself a well-formed expression (right? [1]), then there are at least as many well-formed expressions as there are natural numbers. And clearly there are even more well-formed expressions than that, since for example, each $i + 1$ is also a well formed expression.

So piggy backing off the diagonal idea, it seems similarly that the number of well-formed expressions in a formal system is greater than the number of natural numbers. And wouldn't that mean that Godel-numbering itself is impossible in any given formal system?

It seems to be a similar point reached in each proof leads to different outcomes. Why doesn't Godel's proof similarly lead to the result that "Godel-numbering a formal system is impossible"?

Please excuse that I am not a mathematician and only have kind of a tenuous grip on both proofs, or on the idea of "distinct infinities".

[1] I'm not sure if an natural number by itself is a well-formed expression, but it doesn't matter, since each $i = i$ is clearly a well-formed expression.

Comment: You have only countably many symbols available with which to form well-formed expressions, and each well-formed expression is finite, so there are only countably many well-formed expressions, just as there are only countably many finite sequences of natural numbers. Thus, the cardinality of the set of well-formed expressions is the same as the cardinality of the set of natural numbers.

Comment: I follow generally, but I guess I need to read a lot more on what makes a set countable or not.

Comment: Nope, re-reading your comment and thinking about it. I can see why it is countable. For example you can sort by length and have within each all combination of possible symbols (then filtered to well-formed). Both the length and the number of symbols is finite, as you said. So it is countable. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be very careful when arguing with infinities.  Consider this part of your argument:

> If any natural number is itself a well-formed expression (right?), then there are at least as many well-formed expressions as there are natural numbers. And clearly there are even more well-formed expressions than that, since for example, each $i+1$ is also a well formed expression.

Everything you said is right, but we cannot conclude from this argument that the number of well-formed expressions is greater than the number of natural numbers.  For finite sets, your argument would be correct, but not in the case of infinite sets.  Remember that if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then the definition of $|A| < |B|$ (i.e., there are more elements in $B$ than $A$) is that there is an *injective* map from $A$ to $B$, but there is no map from $A$ to $B$ which is both *injective* and *surjective*.  (Please look up the definitions of those terms if you are not familiar with them.)

Now let's state your argument formally.

Let $A$ be the set of natural numbers.

Let $B$ be the set of well-formed expressions.

Your argument states that there is an injective map $f : A \to B$, sending each natural number $n$ to a well-formed expression $n$.  And then you have stated that there are even more well-formed expressions which are not in the image of $f$, i.e., $f$ is not surjective. That is all correct.

If $A$ and $B$ were finite sets, this would be enough to conclude that $|A| < |B|$, but not in the case of infinite sets.  For in the infinite case, the existence of the injective map $f$ is not enough to preclude the existence of a *different* map $g: A \to B$ which is both injective and surjective.

To see an example of this, let $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ be the natural numbers. Consider a map $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(n) = n+1$.  Then $f$ is clearly injective, and $f$ is not surjective because 0 is not the image of $f$.

However, it is obviously not true that $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{N}|$, because there is another map $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ which is both injective and surjective, namely $g(n) = n$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is all brilliant and (after a little reading) makes sense to me. However, what is it about Cantor's diagonal argument that is able to escape this? Maybe I need more reading on Cantor's method instead. And also, is there such an f that would be a injective/surjective map between natural numbers and well formed expressions? Maybe this is demonstrated in the details of Godel's proof, but not in the book.

Comment: Godel-numering itself is such an f! At least a surjective one onto well-formed expressions. OK. Thanks!